# entity framework linq include and grouping

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm trying  to  to do include and group in in one sentence

```
var instanceIdList = context.
    Tracks.
    Include("Services").
    GroupBy(x => x.ServiceId).
    Take(top);
```

but when I check the result at debug I cant see any of the include values

I tried to do in another way

```
var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
var set = objectContext.CreateObjectSet<Track>();
var instanceIdList = set.Include("Services").GroupBy(x => x.ServiceId);
```

this is the classes :
 *Track*

```
  public partial class Track
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public System.Guid ServiceId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> ServiceInterfaceId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> ProviderId { get; set; }
    public System.Guid ServiceInstanceId { get; set; }
    public System.Guid ActivityParentId { get; set; }
    public System.Guid ActivityInstanceId { get; set; }
    public int ActivityType { get; set; }
    public int ServiceRole { get; set; }
    public int TrackOrder { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Datetime { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> MessageId { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ESBErrorCode { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ESBTecnicalErrorCode { get; set; }
    public string ErrorDescription { get; set; }
    public string PortName { get; set; }
    public string MachineName { get; set; }
    public string ConsumerId { get; set; }
    public string ExternalId { get; set; }
    public string ConsumerMachineName { get; set; }
    public int ServiceBehavior { get; set; }

    public virtual Message Message { get; set; }
}
```

*Service*

```
      public partial class Service
      {
        public Service()
        {
        this.Providers = new HashSet<Provider>();
        this.ServiceInterfaces = new HashSet<ServiceInterface>();
            }

    public System.Guid ServiceId { get; set; }
    public string ServiceName { get; set; }
    public string ServiceNumber { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> ModelSchemaId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Provider> Providers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ServiceInterface> ServiceInterfaces { get; set; }
}
```

but the result is the same

thanks

miki

Comment: What is the relationship between Tracks and Services?

Comment: @JeffreyABecker i added the classes , there is no relationship

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to put include in the end.

Like this...

```
var instanceIdList = context.Tracks
                            .GroupBy(x => x.ServiceId)
                            .Take(top)
                            .Include("Services");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not defined any navigation property for `Services` in your `Track` class, you need to add the following property.

```
public virtual ICollection<Service> Services { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Track class has no member accessor called service, so

```
Include("Services")
```

won't work.

You need to link to Service from Track, e.g.

```
public Service Services {get;set;}
```